# how to create a filesystem database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, filesystems

i been trying to create a filesystem using php,at first i was using php file management method,like readdir,mkdir etc.but lots of people says that the database is much faster,but when i think about it , its just i dont konw how to create the database.

the filesystem should allow people to:

1. create new folder.
2. uploading file to user created folder.

each folder will have some file or not depending on user,and user can create a another folder inside a folder. am confused，folder----file,how to create the database like this?

Comment: Why do you need this? Any specific task you want to achieve?

Comment: Why would a database (which is [normally] backed by a file on a filesystem) be faster than the filesystem (which is designed for files) at common file operations? Anyway, consider this simple "recursive" table: `folderId|parentFolderId(->folderId)|folderName`  and a file: `fileId|parentFolderId(->folderId)|fileName|fileData`.

Comment: the filesystem i want to create is exactly like the one on the desktop.

Comment: There are lots of open source projects for your question. I believe those open source projects could be really good sources to help you to learn as you can download the source code, and they are proven cause millions of users are using them.

For example: http://ajaxplorer.info/.

Answer (score 0):

I want to make something like that too,
My research shows that you can create a system file similar to Windows
Now we are talking about how to create database tables.

All elements must be stored in a table and have a parent-child relationship
Like the example below

```
medias table
------
id
user_id
parent_id
type
name
data

user_id = relationship to user table
parent_id = Refers to the parent ID
type = folder,file
name = file name
data = To store other file components such as file size and type and so on
```

When we design the table as follows, we get a much better query
If you have any comments, please let us know so that we can complete this article

Answer (score 0):

my approach to this type of requirement would be to create two tables which are

##### folders table

```
create table folders
(
    id bigserial primary key,
    user_id bigint                          not null,
    folder_id   bigint ,
    folder_name varchar(255)                not null,
    status      integer default 0           not null,
    deleted_at  timestamp(0) with time zone,
    updated_at  timestamp(0) with time zone not null,
    created_at  timestamp(0) with time zone not null
 );
```

##### folders file table

```
create table folder_files
(
id                bigserial,
user_id           bigint                      not null,
folder_id         bigint,
unique_filename   varchar(255)                not null,
original_filename varchar(255)                not null,
file_extension    varchar(255)                not null,
file_size         bigint                      not null,
status            integer default 0           not null,
deleted_at        timestamp(0) with time zone,
updated_at        timestamp(0) with time zone not null,
created_at        timestamp(0) with time zone not null,
 );
```

the unique_filename is the name to save files by to avoid duplicates and the original_filename is the name of the file as it was being uploaded upload. which will be displayed to the user.

how the tables relate to each other.

> user adds a folder/file and specifies the folder_id (which is the foreign key to the same folders table for an existing folder) that the folder is to be located in. leave folder_id  as `null` (empty) if the folders or file is to be located in the root directory.

###### NB: NOTE THAT WITH THIS APPROACH IT IS POSSIBLE THAT YOU WOULD NOT EVEN NEED TO CREATE FILES AND FOLDERS IN THE ACTUAL HIERARCHY IN THE DATABASE. IT IS ADVISED THAT YOU CREATE FILES AND FOLDERS THOUGH

I am still playing around with this strategy please share if there are any drawbacks to this approach.

when getting files you do not need to check files on disk you just return results from DB and then get files from a disk on request which is faster than recursively checking files hierarchy

file-path for viewing the files depends on which approach you take either creating the actual hierarchy on disk or just creating DB record and display as per DB record then request file on request which means you will not have actual folders, only files with unique names but actual name stored on DB for viewing. AGAIN it is recommended to have an actual file hierarchy unless you will be storing file names with UID and then record the actual name for the file in the DB for when you want to add a file with the same name in a different folder (which in this case only exist in DB) and the actual files are still in the same folder as other files. look up flat file system (eg. AWS s3) vs hierarchical file system (eg Google Cloud Storage)